# Jdbi's declarative API performance hit on a Spring MVC Web Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbi

The Jdbi 3 documentation, regarding their Declarative API, [states](http://jdbi.org/#_sql_objects):

> At runtime, you can request an instance of your interface, and Jdbi synthesizes an implementation based on the annotations and methods you declared.

This means that every single request made, at least one interface is implemented at runtime (assuming all request access the database). At what scale would this hinder the performance of a Spring MVC web service, if at all?

Comment: Jdbi project member here. I don't exactly understand your question, but I can say that the first time you request a particular SQL object type, Jdbi scans the interface once, and produces a command object for each method. The result of that scan is cached, and every instance of a SQL object type reuses the same command objects.

Comment: Ah that settles it then, didn't find anything on the documentation related to that so I had to ask. Looking back, it's kind of obvious that there had to be some kind of caching system involved. Thanks!